# Details component for Taxonomy - Self items

Tags: content-hub, taxonomy

I am creating a detail page for a taxonomy value and I want to show only the Parent field.
My problem is Details component only allows me to show Self items field, that shows both Child and Parent, not allowing me to choose.

And I can see in the Entity definition that it has 2 separate field.

Is there a possible way to display only the Parent?

[image]

Comment: Provide some screenshot please.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by condition -

1. Go To the Schema section where these 2 fields are there.
2. On the child item click on 3 dots -

[image]

3. Go to condition tab -

[image]

4. Show/Hide field based on condition.